# Need help to improve my Computer vision model, It's getting only 88% accuracy on test dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to work on the Kaggle dataset(10_monkey_dataset), and I am not getting good accuracy on my model.

here is the full model is written in karas.

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

With `batch_size = 32 epochs = 350`

I had trained it on google colab.

Here I am attaching the graph:

[image]

Full code can be found on my GitHub:
https://github.com/harsh52/10_monkey_species_kaggle_dataset/blob/master/CNN_monkey.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your model is overfitting as your train accuracy is way higher than your test accuracy. I would suggest applying any of the following techniques:

- L1/L2 regularization
- Adding more dropout
- Batch normalization
- Trying a smaller network architecture

You might also want to try the leaky relu activation function as this sometimes gives better results.

Also checkout [this Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/crawford/monkey-classifier-cnn-xception-0-90-acc), this guy seems to get a better accuracy with a more simple model.

Comment: This is not a simpler model, he is using Xception as feature extractor

Answer (score 1):

There is really many things you can do in order to improve your accuracy :

## Model architecture

1. You can add more convolutional layer per bloc. A "bloc" is the combinaison of multiple layers like (CONV -> RELU -> CONV -> RELU - > BATCHNORM -> MAXPOOL)
2. You can add more blocs in order to have a deeper model
3. You can add batchnorm as said by @Daan Klijn, it can give more stability to your network and lower the overfitting
4. You can increase your model width, by increasing the number of filters
5. Add more complexe bloc, like squeeze and excite bloc (https://github.com/titu1994/keras-squeeze-excite-network), residual bloc, inception bloc

Exemple of model architecture :

```
Bloc1 : 3 conv with 32 filters
Bloc2 : 3 conv with 64 filters
Bloc2 : 3 conv with 128 filters
Bloc2 : 3 conv with 256 filters
```

## Data preparation

1. You can preprocess your data by normalizing it
2. Add data augmentation (rotation, shifting, brightness, ...)

## Other thing

1. Tweek your hypermaters, change optimizer (Adam, SGD, ..), change learning rate

Exemple of one bloc with 2 conv and 32 filters:

```py
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3) , padding='SAME')(model_input)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3) , padding='SAME')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
```

Exemple of one bloc with 3 conv and 64filters:

```py
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3) , padding='SAME')(model_input)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3) , padding='SAME')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3) , padding='SAME')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with other great answers you may also try different `activation functions` to get 1% more accuracy. I saw `Mish` activation function giving some good results.

https://github.com/digantamisra98/Mish

https://forums.fast.ai/t/meet-mish-new-activation-function-possible-successor-to-relu/53299/76